# Codeigniter, windows, xampp, how to use htaccess to get rid of trailing slash?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter

So I've used a .htaccess file which I searched for on here, I use this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Which gets rid of the index.php file as wanted. I have the .htaccess file in the codeigniter directory. The website displays fine using this link with the trailing slash:

```
http://localhost/codeigniter/home/
```

But going to the link but without the slash after the home.php shows my website looking like it has not been linked to a css file. Any suggestions?

Also, in my `config.php` file I have edited the index page:

```
$config['index_page'] = "";
```

If that makes any difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine on

# Next two lines get rid of trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ $1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

also base_url in config file should be

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/codeigniter/';
```

You should post code from view file to let us determine what is going on. I assume you are using some kind of relative path though. Try using something like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url('resources/css/main.css'); ?>">
```

Don't forget to load url helper before.